# C# Linq query calculate percentage from integer

Tags: c#, linq

```
Country TotalSales
UK          2512793.05
USA         119176.75
AUST    83599.25
GERM    45613.75
IREL    43352.50
SWED    32955.75
```

Then I have:

```
var list = new List<int> { 2512793, 119176, 83599, 45613, 43352 };
```

How to convert to Percentage list from above list. please advise.

E.G: {45%, 20%, 15%, 12%, 8% }

Comment: How are you calculating percentages? % of sum ?

Comment: "*How to convert to Percentage list from above list*" eh?

Comment: Calculate the `Sum`, then divide `Each` element by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the list to a decimal list, and use something like the following :

```
var list = new List<decimal> { 2512793, 119176, 83599, 45613, 43352 };
decimal sum = list.Sum();
var perc = list.Select(x => (x / sum) * 100);
```

Alternatively, you can cast each value as decimal.

Or Alternatively as @James Pointed out there is no need to multiply by 100 if you need to output the value.

```
var perc = list.Select(x => x / sum);
Console.WriteLine(perc.FirstOrDefault().ToString("P")); // Output the first value
```

Comment: Alternatively, remove the `* 100` part, given the percentile you can use the [percent format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#PFormatString) when displaying.

Comment: If the OP is looking for an array of percentage strings `list.Select(x => (x / sum).ToString("P%"));`

Comment: @James OP was unclear on what he was asking, but since this answer is accepted, I will leave it as is.

Comment: no worries, although from the OPs example it does look as though that's what he is after.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try

```
  var list = new List<int> {2512793, 119176, 83599, 45613, 43352 };
  var percentage1 = list.Select(ele => (ele * 100) / list.Sum());
```